# How to perform batch operations in YII Framework?

Tags: php, yii2, batch-processing

Now I'm working with a big project written on PHP + YII framework.
Now there is a task where it is required to import data from a big json-file into the database.

I'm afraid that this process would take several dozen of minutes or even several hours, so it wouldn't have time to complete during one http-request.

Could you clarify me, if you have worked with YII Framework, how I could solve this problem?

For example, in Drupal there is Batch API, that can allow split a big operation into several small ones.
Are there any similar solution in YII Framework?
Or maybe is there an external PHP library/framework for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `yii\console\Controller` that can be run from cli (c.f. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-console-controller)

To split the operation into smaller pieces you could use `yii-queue` (c.f. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii-queue)